# Clear a matplotlib plot in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt

My code opens a PyQt window with a matplotlib plot inside of it. At the top there are 10 buttons, each with their own data values to plot. I want to know how can I clear the previous plot that is currently showing and then plot the new one when I click on the buttons.

I use PyQt4 and Python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
import sys
import os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

plt.style.use('ggplot')

def Extract_Data(name):

    #setting up lists

    Stim_trig = []
    Stim_order = []
    Sch_wav = []

    data = scipy.io.loadmat(name)

    for k,v in data.items():

        #Sends Sch_wav data to a list
        if "Sch_wav" in k:

            for d in (((v[0])[0])[4]):
                Sch_wav.append(d[0])

        #Sends StimTrig to a list
        if k=="StimTrig":
            for g in (((v[0])[0])[4]):
                Stim_trig.append(g[0])
            Stim_trig.append(Stim_trig[-1]+1)

        #Sends Stim order to a list

            for w in (((v[0])[0])[5]):
                Stim_order.append(w[0])

    superdata = []

    #Prepares grouping stimuli and trigger

    for i in range(len(Stim_trig)-1):
        fire = []
        for p in Sch_wav:
            if p > Stim_trig[i] and p < Stim_trig[i+1]:
                fire.append(p - Stim_trig[i])
        superdata.append([Stim_order[i],fire])


    #sorts all the data
    superdata.sort()

    alladdedup = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[62]]
    count = 0
    for d in superdata:
        if d[0] == (alladdedup[count])[0]:
            for j in d[1]:
                ((alladdedup)[count]).append(j)
        else:
            count += 1
    #places time stamps of triggers in lists for each trigger

    for l in alladdedup:
        l.pop(0)
        l.sort()
        #removes title and sorts data

    ffmsb = []

    #finds number of firings for each milisecond bin
    for v in alladdedup:
        fmsb = []

        for b in range(1000):
            msbc = b/1000
            msb = []

            for t in v:
                if t > msbc and t < msbc + 0.001:
                    msb.append(t)

            fmsb.append(len(msb))

        ffmsb.append(fmsb)
    #returns list of stimuli firings per milisecond bin
    return(ffmsb)

class DisplayWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisplayWidget, self).__init__( parent )

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.main_frame = QWidget()

        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)

        self.one = QPushButton('Intensity 1')
        self.two = QPushButton('Intensity 2')
        self.three = QPushButton('Intensity 3')
        self.four = QPushButton('Intensity 4')
        self.five = QPushButton('Intensity 5')
        self.six = QPushButton('Intensity 6')
        self.seven = QPushButton('Intensity 7')
        self.eight = QPushButton('Intensity 8')
        self.nine = QPushButton('Intensity 9')
        self.ten = QPushButton('Intensity 10')

        self.one.connect(self.one, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_one)
        self.two.connect(self.two, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_two)
        self.three.connect(self.three, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_three)
        self.four.connect(self.four, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_four)
        self.five.connect(self.five, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_five)
        self.six.connect(self.six, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_six)
        self.seven.connect(self.seven, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_seven)
        self.eight.connect(self.eight, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_eight)
        self.nine.connect(self.nine, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_nine)
        self.ten.connect(self.ten, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setIntensity_ten)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.canvas, 1, 0, 10, 10)  # the matplotlib canvas
        grid.addWidget(self.one, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.two, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.three, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.four, 0, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.five, 0, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.six, 0, 5)
        grid.addWidget(self.seven, 0, 6)
        grid.addWidget(self.eight, 0, 7)
        grid.addWidget(self.nine, 0, 8)
        grid.addWidget(self.ten, 0, 9)



        self.main_frame.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)
        self.setWindowTitle('Neurons')

        self.showMaximized()

    def setIntensity_one(self):
        self.data(intensity = 1)

    def setIntensity_two(self):
        self.data(intensity = 2)

    def setIntensity_three(self):
        self.data(intensity = 3)

    def setIntensity_four(self):
        self.data(intensity = 4)

    def setIntensity_five(self):
        self.data(intensity = 5)

    def setIntensity_six(self):
        self.data(intensity = 6)

    def setIntensity_seven(self):
        self.data(intensity = 7)

    def setIntensity_eight(self):
        self.data(intensity = 8)

    def setIntensity_nine(self):
        self.data(intensity = 9)

    def setIntensity_ten(self):
        self.data(intensity = 10)


    def data(self, intensity):
        stimuli = (Extract_Data("654508_rec02_all.mat")[intensity])

        numberlist = []
        for i in range(1000):
            numberlist.append(i/1000)

        d = pd.Series(stimuli, index = numberlist)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(d)
        self.canvas.plot_data_frame(self.df)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas, DisplayWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 12, height = 9):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (width, height))
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)


        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


    def plot_data_frame(self, df):

        df.plot( ax = self.axes,
            kind = 'line',
            title = 'Number of neurons firing',
            legend = False,
            xlim = (0, 1))
        self.draw()        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication( [] )
    widget = DisplayWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should put a code the other people could run by just copy&paste. Don't put reference to your own local data files, or add them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `self.axes.cla()` before each plot at your `plot_data_frame` function. This will clear the axes.